# React Google Login and passport google auth20

Tags: reactjs, passport-google-oauth, react-google-login

What is the difference between React Google Login and passport google auth20 and which one should i choose?

Answer (score 0):

recently google has deprecated the npm package "react-google-login" and there are other packages for frontend authentication such as "react-oauth/google".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).